# Revert commits unique to a branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-revert

I have just finished fixing an extremely long merge conflict and then realised I merged to the wrong branch! I merged to `dev-majorversion` when I meant to merge to `dev-majorversion.minorversion`.
Is there any way I can undo the commits that exist on `majorversion` but do not exist on `minorversion` for branch to undo these commits, or will I need to merge again?

Answer (score 1):

You could cherry-pick your merge resolution:

```
git checkout dev-majorversion.minorversion
git cherry-pick <SHA1 of commit resolving merge>
git merge --ours <yourBranchToMerge> # the one your already merge into the wrong branch
```

The git merge --ours records the merge between `<yourBranchToMerge>` and `dev-majorversion.minorversion`, but keeps the content of `dev-majorversion.minorversion` intact (including its cherry-picked commit).

You would still have to validate that the commit cherry-picked is compatible with the content of `dev-majorversion.minorversion` (since it represents conflict resolution initially done on `dev-majorversion`)

If so, you can go back to `dev-majorversion` and reset HEAD to the previous commit to cancel the merge done here (assuming the merge was the last operation done on `dev-majorversion`, and that is wasn't pushed yet)

```
git checkout dev-majorversion
git reset --hard @~
```